# Application fails if not in its directory?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I'm trying to run DeaDBeeF, a music player. It works fine if I'm in its directory, but if I'm anywhere else, it tells me that it "failed to find output plugin". Is there any way to get it to look in its own directory instead of my present working directory?

Comment: How did you obtain the binary? Run `strace -efile deadbeef` and see what calls are failing (post the output if you don't know how to interpret it).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a bug in that program. You probably can't fix it without modifying the source code, but you can easily work around it, for example with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/to/program
exec ./program "$@"
```

Save this in `/usr/local/bin`, set the correct permissions:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/myscript
chown root:root /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

and then launch this script instead of the program executable.

A limitation of this approach is that you can no longer play files in the current directory simply by typing their name. Instead of `deadbeef myfile.mp3`, you can use `deadbeef $PWD/myfile.mp3` (make that `deadbeef "$PWD/myfile.mp3"` if the name of the current directory contains `\[?*` or whitespace).